# How do I set values of existing structs?

Tags: rust

Consider the following:

```
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

struct Character {
    name: String,
    hp: i32,
    level: i32,
    xp: i32,
    gold: i32
}

impl Character {
    fn new(name: String) -> Character {
        let mut rng = thread_rng();

        let hp: i32 = rng.gen_range(12, 75);
        let gold: i32 = rng.gen_range(10, 50);

        Character { name: name, hp: hp, level: 1, xp: 0, gold: gold }
    }

    fn set_hp(&self, hp: &i32) {
        &self.hp = hp;
    }

    fn get_hp(&self) -> i32 {
        self.hp
    }
}
```

Which generates the following error:

```
error[E0070]: invalid left-hand side expression
  --> src/game/character/Character.rs:22:9
   |
22 |         &self.hp = hp;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ left-hand of expression not valid
```

Why can I not set the `Character.hp` to the value passed in? What's this left hand expression jazz? I couldn't find any info on this in the docs.

Comment: `&self.hp = hp` is trying to assign to a reference, which is clearly not a good idea. `self.hp = hp` (and take `&mut self` instead, because you are *mutating* `self`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax `&foo = bar` doesn't make sense. If it worked, it would mean something like:

1. Take the reference to `foo`.
2. Replace the reference (a pointer) with the *value* of `bar`.

What you want is

```
fn set_hp(&mut self, hp: &i32) {
    self.hp = *hp;
}
```

This *dereferences* the passed-in argument and it is stored in `self.hp`. Note that the `self` argument has to be mutable in order to change the value.

> What's this left hand expression jazz?

Often abbreviated as **LHS**, it's what is on the *left side* of the assignment operation. There are certain things that are valid to be assigned to. For example, `5 = 6` would also be an invalid LHS.

Comment: Note: usually, `Copy`-types like `i32` are not passed by immutable reference, but by value.